# how to attatch a file to the mail using default mail composer

Tags: ipad, email, email-attachments

i hav a file with some data and i want to attach this file to mail, and i am using the default mail composer ...

any idea how to attach the file to mail before sending to receipents....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with an attached image:

```
NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"MyImage"];
```

Comment: i am using MFMailComposeViewController  and if i hav data file (.doc or pdf ) then how should i attach this type files to mail

Comment: Obtain a `NSData *` representation of your file, then attach with the same method, using the appropriate mimeType (Google MIME type if required).

Answer (score 0):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg" ofType:@"jpg"];

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"Attachment-1"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```